# Oracle : How to avoid tablespace issue in pl sql procedure

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-update

I am trying to `update` a column for 5 tables based on a condition. The number of rows in the table is in millions
and tablespace is an issue. I have thought of below options and want to know which option will NOT encouter tablespace issue or
performance wise which is better.

`p_fetch_limit = 1000;`

1. Place update script for all the 5 tables inside the loop. This has been already tested and I am facing tablespace issue with this approach.
2. Open the cursor for updating 1 table. Just place update statement for 1st table. Close the cursor. Open the same cursor. Just place the update statement for 2nd table. Close the cursor. Continue the same steps for rest of the tables.
3. Open the cursor. Update 1st table. Commit. Update 2nd table. Commit. Continue the steps for rest of the table

s.

```
OPEN cur_recs;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_recs BULK COLLECT INTO someCounter LIMIT p_fetch_limit;
    IF (someCounter.COUNT > 0) THEN
                      BEGIN
                           FOR i IN 1 .. someCounter.count
                             LOOP                            
                               UPDATE table1 SET column1 = someDate WHERE column2 = someCounter.idValue and column1 between someDate1 and someDate2;
                               UPDATE table2 SET column = someDate WHERE column2 = someCounter.idValue and column1 between someDate1 and someDate2;
                               UPDATE table3 SET column1 = someDate WHERE column2 = someCounter.idValue and column1 between someDate1 and someDate2;
                   UPDATE table4 SET column1 = someDate WHERE column2 = someCounter.idValue and column1 between someDate1 and someDate2;
                END LOOP; 
                      END;
                COMMIT;
    END IF;
    EXIT WHEN cur_recs%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur_recs;
```

Currently, I am encountering the below tablespace issue.

```
Error report:
ORA-01688: unable to extend table mySchema.table1 partition SYS_P3531 by 1024 in tablespace someTableSpace
01688. 00000 -  "unable to extend table %s.%s partition %s by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent for table segment in tablespace.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.
```

Comment: What 'tablespace issue' are you having? Why are you using cursor loops and row-by-roe updates, or using PL/SQL at all, for what seem to be simple update that should be run as plain SQL?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: All the 5 tables are partitioned tables. `column1` is the partition-key

Comment: You're still going to run out of space in that partition if you're changing the partition key for lots of rows, however you do it. You need to talk to your DBA about making more space available.

Comment: Okay got it. Lets say my table was not partitioned and I want to just update some random non partition-key column. In this situation, which option would be better. I just want to understand an efficient way of updating rows.

Comment: A single update statement is most efficient. If you don't have enough rollback/undo and can't get more then bulk collect, but use `forall` for the update. Use plain SQL whenever you can though.